# What guarantees that RTL inverter is in triode region when the input is high?

Tags: digital-logic, inverter, rtl

in this inverter my instructor says that if Vin is high, we need M to be in triode to have low voltage in the output. now I understand this but I don't know guarantees that it will be in triode. why doesn't it go to saturation.

[image: RTL inverter]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at a typical mosfet characteristic. here's a fairly generic one: -

[image]

Basically, dependent on the drain current, you need Vgs to be high enough to avoid the saturation region. So, when you think you might have a device that is OK read its data sheet and look for the above graph. They always have this graph in the data sheet.

Drain current is largely determined by the load resistor and the voltage on the gate. The voltage on the gate produces the shape of curve in the triode region which, for a given drain current is a reasonable approximation to a resistor - think about the top red curve and concentrate on the triode region - imagine it is a straight line i.e. a constant ratio between Id and Vds - this is often referred to as "the on-resistance" of a FET.

Comment: I don't get your point.  
If ,for example, Vin = Vdd  
what prevents Vout from going up near Vdd and keep the mosfet in saturation!

Comment: If you have such a low resistance load that this happens you do go into saturation so, as I said, it's "dependent on the drain current" i.e. too much drain current for too low a Vgs pushes you into saturation.

Comment: OK, I got your point. but can you make your answer more clear before I mark it as the right answer.

Comment: I mean to clarify that this depends on the value of the resistor. if the resistor is large then the drop would be large and the transistor would go to triode and if it is small then the drop across it may be small that it keeps the transistor in sat

Comment: Consider it clarified.